# Trying to rename large amount of .doc files based off first line or so of text

Tags: powershell, rename

I was attempting to help a friend, who had a bunch of data recovered, but the meta data was lost. As most of it is articles or recipes, she believes the title or first line or so of text will be good enough for a file name.

I wanted to try to use a powershell script to ...access/read the files,  grab the first line (if possible define a length of characters) and then rename.  Like... read the first 10 characters and rename the file that.

I found this script,  which seems to be for .txt files.  Is it at all possible to rework it for .doc  and then eliminate the part about O and just have it read whatever the first line is and rename with the first 10 characters read?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.   (apologies if i mucked up the posting of the script)

```
$myFolderFullOfTextFiles = 'C:\recoveredDocs'
$linesToReadInEachTextFile = 5

$myTextFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $myFolderFullOfTextFiles

foreach( $textFile in $myTextFiles )
{
$newName = ''

foreach( $line in $(Get-Content -Path $textFile.FullName -Head $linesToReadInEachTextFile) )
{
    if( $line -like 'O*' )
    {
       $newName = $textFile.DirectoryName + '\' + $line.Substring(0,6) + '.txt'
    }
}

try
{
    Write-Host $newName
    Rename-Item -Path $textFile.FullName -NewName $newName
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Failed to rename $textFile."
}
```

}

I also found this script.  which is more .doc focused.   All I need is ... read whatever the first line of text is,  rename it  (with some reasonable cap on the characters, such as the first 10 characters).

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Scripts\Test.doc")

strText = objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
arrText = Split(strText, vbTab)
intIndex = Ubound(arrText)
strUserName = arrText(intIndex)

arrUserName = Split(strUserName, " ")
intLength = Len(arrUserName(1))
strName = Left(arrUserName(1), intlength - 1)

strUserName = strName & ", " & arrUserName(0)

strText = objDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text
arrText = Split(strText, vbTab)
intIndex = Ubound(arrText)

strDate = arrText(intIndex)
strDate = Replace(strDate, "/", "")

intLength = Len(strDate)
strDate = Left(strDate, intlength - 1)

strFileName = "C:\Scripts\" &  strUserName & " " & strDate & ".doc"

objWord.Quit

Wscript.Sleep 5000

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.MoveFile "C:\Scripts\Test.doc", strFileName
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't know much about PowerShell scripting based on the broadness of the question and the fact that you don't seem to be able to tell PowerShell from VB, so it sounds like you are asking someone to write a fairly significant script for you, which I think is an unrealistic expectation. There is ready-made software that may do what you want. Do a Google search for "rename word document based on content".

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following code and create as powershell script by naming file with extension .ps1  (tested ok with powershell 4 on Windows 7  - check your version of powershell with "get-host|Select-Object version" or "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion" )

```
 $word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application     <# New word application #>
    $source = 'C:\recoveredDocs'    <# create the source variable #>
    $destination = 'C:\renamedDocs' <# create the destination variable #>

    if (!(Test-Path -path $destination)) {  <# check to see if destination folder exists #>
    New-Item -path $destination\ -type directory -Force  } <# create destination folder if it doesn't already exist #>
    echo 'checking files to convert...'

    <# filter for word .doc files only #>
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.doc? | ForEach-Object {
    if (!(Test-Path "$destination\$($_.BaseName).doc")) {   <# check to see if file is already in destination folder (Note. "!" is a PS Alias for "-Not") #>

    $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)   <# open word document #>

    $pattern = '[^a-zA-Z1234567890 ]'   <# create regex pattern of allowed characters #>

    $textstring = $document.range().text <# get the text string from the document #>

    $titlestring = $textstring -replace $pattern, ''    <# apply the regex pattern to eliminate the reserved characters #>

    $title = $titlestring.substring(0, [System.Math]::Min(10, $titlestring.Length)) <# limit the string to 10 characters #>

    $doc_strNewName = "$destination\$($title).doc"  <# create the new name and path for the doc #>

    echo "$($_.FullName) converted to  $doc_strNewName"

$document.SaveAs([ref] $doc_strNewName, [ref] 0)    <# save the document with new name and path #>

$document.Close()   <# close documnet #>

        }
    }

    echo "No More Files to Convert"

$word_app.Quit()    <# close the word application #>
```